# Зачем в значении свойства font-family писать общее название типа шрифтов?

Tags: css, вёрстка, шрифты

```
body {
 font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
}
```

Зачем указывать общее название типа шрифтов? Почему нельзя указать какую-то гарнитуру?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что никто не гарантирует, что Georgia или Times есть на компьютере (телефоне/кофеварке) пользователя. А `serif` подсказывает, что надо показать какой-нибудь шрифт с засечками. Хотя и это тоже не гарантируется.